# Enabling demography in google analytics for android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

According to Google. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872

I need to make following changes to enable demography changes.
For android

```
t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
```

For iOS

```
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

Do I also need to do advertisement to use this feature ? Is it safe to use this feature without any advertisement ?

Answer (score 0):

Democratic is useful feature for mobile apps  , This is how you can enable in at server to affect you mobile apps.

http://www.gravitatedesign.com/blog/google-analytics-now-includes-useful-persona-information/